# Vue sound components overlapping and not interrupting eachother

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I've been struggling with this little soundboard I've been doing. I'm using the [vueuse/sound](https://github.com/vueuse/sound) API and I managed to get it to reproduce both my sounds by making each individual button a component.

The problem is that they don't interrupt eachother. Each button press reproduces the sound but overlaps with the one that's playing at that moment, despite `interrupt:true` being added in both components.

This is the button sample, I simply cloned it:

```
<template>
  <sound-player></sound-player>
  <br>
  <kick></kick>
</template>

<script>
import SoundPlayer from './components/sound-player.vue'
import kick from './components/kick.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    SoundPlayer,
    kick,
  },
}
</script>
```

and here's the component snippet:

```
<template>
  <button @click="play">Play a kick</button>
</template>

<script>

import { useSound } from '@vueuse/sound'
import kickSfx from '../assets/kick.mp3'


export default {
  setup() {
    const volume = 5;
    
    const { play } = useSound(kickSfx, {
      volume,
      interrupt: true
    })
    
    return {
      play,
      volume,
    }
    
  },
}
</script>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `interrupt` obviously affects the same `play` instance, it would be confusing if it affected global sound state somehow.

Comment: Yeah, I sorta figured as much. But how can I circumvent this? Or is there a way of making `interrupt` global?

Comment: You need to maintain play state by yourself globally, with Vuex or else